# What is the HTML 4 DTD role in HTML5

Tags: html, html5

All, I know there are three types of `DTD` for `HTML 4.01` (strict, transitional, and frameset). And I knew the `DTD` defines the syntax of markup constructs and the document structure with a list of legal elements and attributes.

So why is `DTD` missing in `HTML 5`? Isn't it necessary for `HTML 5 document`? Or no need to specify `DTD` for `HTML5` because of only one `DTD` for `HTML 5` by default ? Any special reason for removing `DTD` for `HTML5`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 is not an application of SGML, therefore it doesn't need an SGML DTD. I'm pretty sure that there are some things in HTML5 that are illegal in SGML, so even if you wanted to, you couldn't create an SGML DTD for HTML5.

Comment: I wonder how the HTML5 document been validated without DTD. Thanks.

Comment: There are several features in HTML5 that prevent the construction of a DTD for it; see http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html5-dtd.html for some notes.

Comment: @Joe.wang, validators use ad hoc code for dealing with HTML5. They use schema-based parsing.

Comment: @Joe.wang: it is validated against the HTML5 specification, not against an SGML schema.